# CompileITunesMetadata takes a very long time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

When compiling a Xamarin.Forms app for iOS, the task CompileITunesMetaData takes about 15 seconds on every build.

Two questions:

1. Is it normal it takes such a long time?
2. Can we get rid of this step? The app we are developing is a business app that is not going to be published in the App store but will be deployed using Cisco Meraki.

Answer (score 0):

For non-App Store distributions you actually need the iTunes MetaData to provide missing information about the `.ipa`. In an App Store distribution this information is **not** needed and this `.plist` should never be included in your app bundle (will actually cause a Store rejection).

Thus Meraki Systems Manager (iTunes/Apple Configurator/etc...) needs this information for deployment.

1) I have not *personally* seen it take that long. The process that it is doing is fairly simple. Refer to the source code link for details of what is taking place during that task/step:

Ref: [CompileITunesMetadataTaskBase.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/2edb2ae4f5bb371a7006731987717c01f8725420/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Core/Tasks/CompileITunesMetadataTaskBase.cs)

2) Run a complete build from a cleaned solution with Diagnostic output (`/verbosity:diagnostic`) and review the end of the output for the performance summaries (`Target` and `Task`) to confirm where the time is being spent.

3)[The iTunesMetadata.plist File](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/itunesmetadata/) info

> **iTunesMetadata.plist file used to provide information to iTunes about an iOS application using Ad Hoc distribution for either testing or Enterprise deployment.**
>
> When an iOS application is created in iTune Connect (either for sale or free release from the iTunes App Store), the developer can specify information such as the application's genre, sub genre, copyright notice, supported iOS devices and required device capabilities. **For iOS applications that are delivered either to testers or Enterprise user via ad hoc distribution, this information is missing.**

Comment: +/- 25% is consumed in the CompileITunesMetadata task
4>    15293 ms  CompileITunesMetadata                      1 calls
4>    41894 ms  MTouch                                     1 calls

Comment: @gsharp What type of Mac hardware do you have? Ram and disk speed issues maybe? You can manually create and maintain this plist : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/itunesmetadata/#Creating_an_iTunesMetadata.plist_File

Comment: I'm developing in Visual Studio and I'm connected to a MacBook Pro. If I look at the source code of the CompileITunesMetadata task then it seems like nothing too fancy is happening here. I also already tried adding a plist manually but it takes the same amount of time.